# video mimetype .mpg

Tags: php, centos, mime-types

I'm using a php function finfo_file to determine mimetype and it keeps reporting .mpg files as application/octet-stream instead of video/mpeg.

I'm using CentOS, and in /etc/mime.types I see:

```
# grep 'mpg' /etc/mime.types 
audio/mpeg          mpga mp2 mp3
video/mpeg          mpeg mpg mpe
```

Updated below is sample code:

```
$file = '/tmp/sample.mpg';
$fi = new finfo( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
echo $fi->file( $file );
```

outputs:

```
application/octet-stream
```

Comment: You need to post some of your code, showing your `finfo_open()` call. And this programming question would probably do better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I was originally going to post it there but I thought the solution was probably non-php related, and something about mime types or magic files on CentOS or in Apache even.

Comment: SF can help with installing magic files and configuring your server, but designing your PHP code to do what you want is probably best at SO. So it sort of depends on what the issue ends up being. Hopefully that gives you some idea of what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These PHP functions depend on supplying a *magic file* which provides data to analyze a file's content to determine its type. On a Unix system, this functionality is exposed via the `file` command.

At no time does it ever look at `/etc/mime.types`.

Since you didn't specify a path to the magic file in your constructor, PHP uses `/usr/share/misc/magic` by default. In CentOS, this file is provided by the `file-libs` package. If the package is missing or corrupt, you may get unexpected results.

Comment: if I type 'file /tmp/sample.mpg' I get 'MPEG sequence, v2, program multiplex' if that helps.  If I pass '/usr/share/misc/magic' to the finfo() above it reports a failure to load /usr/share/misc/magic.

Comment: Maybe you're running CentOS 5 and the magic file is elsewhere. I don't have any old CentOS 5 boxes anymore so I couldn't tell you exactly where it's located, but you should be able to poke around and find it.